# XKB multi-layout layout specific Capslock behaviour oddity

Tags: xkb, xubuntu

I have two custom keyboard layouts, one a modified version of the `us` (which I have called `vi`,) one a modified version of the `dk` (which I have called `da`.)

Both are registered properly, and work. After a fashion.

The `vi` has Capslock and Escape swapped identical to how it is done in the `capslock(swapescape)` partial layout, and has a specified Compose key (the `<LSGT>` key, which is unusued in `us` on a `pc105`, but used for `<>\¬` with `dk`.)

(Obviously `vi` is one I made for Vi-like editors. The reason why I don't just set `caps:swapescape, compose:102` is because that will also affect the `dk` layout — namely blotting out the ability to enter the symbols `<>\¬`.)

The problem I initially encountered was that my `vi` layout would swap Capslock and Escape, and that this would bleed over into the native `dk` layout.

Then I created the `da` layout which attempts to rectify this, by specifying that Capslock is indeed Capslock, and that Escape is indeed Escape.

And this *almost* works. Now they both act as Capslock when the `da` layout is selected.

How do I make sure Escape is Escape and Capslock is Capslock in `da` while retaining the swapped behavior in `vi`?

**ETA:** I have now tried to reverse the order of these two layouts (so the layouts read `da,vi`) and the error has promptly switched: now both of `vi`'s are Capslock, and `da` has the normal way.

---

I am on Xubuntu 14.04

`vi` layout file:

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    name[Group1]= "English (US) with Caps:SwapEscape and Compose:102";

    key <TLDE> {    [     grave,    asciitilde  ]   };
    key <AE01> {    [     1,    exclam      ]   };
    key <AE02> {    [     2,    at      ]   };
    key <AE03> {    [     3,    numbersign  ]   };
    key <AE04> {    [     4,    dollar      ]   };
    key <AE05> {    [     5,    percent     ]   };
    key <AE06> {    [     6,    asciicircum ]   };
    key <AE07> {    [     7,    ampersand   ]   };
    key <AE08> {    [     8,    asterisk    ]   };
    key <AE09> {    [     9,    parenleft   ]   };
    key <AE10> {    [     0,    parenright  ]   };
    key <AE11> {    [     minus,    underscore  ]   };
    key <AE12> {    [     equal,    plus        ]   };

    key <AD01> {    [     q,    Q       ]   };
    key <AD02> {    [     w,    W       ]   };
    key <AD03> {    [     e,    E       ]   };
    key <AD04> {    [     r,    R       ]   };
    key <AD05> {    [     t,    T       ]   };
    key <AD06> {    [     y,    Y       ]   };
    key <AD07> {    [     u,    U       ]   };
    key <AD08> {    [     i,    I       ]   };
    key <AD09> {    [     o,    O       ]   };
    key <AD10> {    [     p,    P       ]   };
    key <AD11> {    [ bracketleft,  braceleft   ]   };
    key <AD12> {    [ bracketright, braceright  ]   };

    key <AC01> {    [     a,    A       ]   };
    key <AC02> {    [     s,    S       ]   };
    key <AC03> {    [     d,    D       ]   };
    key <AC04> {    [     f,    F       ]   };
    key <AC05> {    [     g,    G       ]   };
    key <AC06> {    [     h,    H       ]   };
    key <AC07> {    [     j,    J       ]   };
    key <AC08> {    [     k,    K       ]   };
    key <AC09> {    [     l,    L       ]   };
    key <AC10> {    [ semicolon,    colon       ]   };
    key <AC11> {    [ apostrophe,   quotedbl    ]   };

    key <AB01> {    [     z,    Z       ]   };
    key <AB02> {    [     x,    X       ]   };
    key <AB03> {    [     c,    C       ]   };
    key <AB04> {    [     v,    V       ]   };
    key <AB05> {    [     b,    B       ]   };
    key <AB06> {    [     n,    N       ]   };
    key <AB07> {    [     m,    M       ]   };
    key <AB08> {    [     comma,    less        ]   };
    key <AB09> {    [    period,    greater     ]   };
    key <AB10> {    [     slash,    question    ]   };

    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,         bar    ]   };

    key <CAPS> { [ Escape ] };
    key <ESC>  { [ Caps_Lock ] };
    key <LSGT> { type[Group1]="TWO_LEVEL", [ Multi_key, Multi_key ] };
};
```

`da` layout file:

```
// based on a keyboard map from an 'xkb/symbols/dk' file

default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    include "latin(type2)"

    name[Group1]="Danish";

    key <AE11>  { [      plus,   question,    plusminus, questiondown ] };
    key <AE12>  { [dead_acute, dead_grave,          bar,    brokenbar ] };


    key <AC10>  { [        ae,        AE,   dead_acute, dead_doubleacute ] };
    key <AC11>  { [    oslash,  Ooblique, dead_circumflex, dead_caron ] };
    key <TLDE>  { [   onehalf,   section, threequarters,    paragraph ] };

    key <BKSL>  { [apostrophe,   asterisk, dead_doubleacute, multiply ] };

    key <LSGT>  { [      less,    greater,    backslash,      notsign ] };

    include "kpdl(comma)"

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"

    key <ESC>  { [ Escape ] };
    key <CAPS> { [ Caps_Lock ] };

};
```

`setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     vi,da
variant:    ,
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+vi+da:2+inet(evdev)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+vi+da:2+inet(evdev)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting both layouts in the same file using explicit [Group]'s:

`key <...>  { symbols[Group1] = [ ... ], symbols[Group2] = [ ... ] };`